# How Can I combine three independent studies/topics in one Thesis in LaTex?

Tags: combine

```
\documentclass[14.49998pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %to plot figure
\usepackage{array, blkarray, tabularx, longtable, multirow,threeparttable, makecell, booktabs, caption} 
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{booktabs}         %to use \toprule and \bottomrule without error message
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %to plot figure
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.3} % default numerical column spec
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % default is 6pt
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage{subfigure}        % to add subfigures
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\textbf{#1}}%  to make heads of table in BOLD, it is used with booktabs package and \head
\usepackage{url} \makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds} \makeatother
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url} \makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds} \makeatother
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs,csvsimple}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm} % needed for command eqref or Math packages
\usepackage{amssymb} % needed for math fonts
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true
   ,breaklinks
   %, ngerman
    ] {hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the docuent, the option colorlink=true gets rid of the awful boxes, breaklinks breaks lonk links (list of figures), and the ngerman sets everthing for german s default hyperlink languages.
%\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor {c1}{rgb}{0,0, 1} % blue
\definecolor {c2}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % light blue
\definecolor {c3}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % red blue
\hypersetup{
   linkcolor={c1}, % internal links
    citecolor={c2}, % citations 
    urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
}

%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for abbrvant bibliography style
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % needed for displaying bibliography and other in the table of contents
\usepackage{graphicx} % needed for\includegraphics
%\imp{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable} % needed for long tables over pages
\usepackage{bigstrut} % needed for the  command \bigstrut
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{blkarray}
%\usepackage{todonotes} % needed for todos
\usepackage{makeidx}  % needed for creating an index
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext} % needed for creating dummy text passage
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % needed for displayng bibliography and other in the able of contents
%\usepackage{figures}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
%\usepackage[T]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,
                    labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[table]{font={footnotesize,sc},
                      labelsep=newline,
                      justification=centering}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*, fill=white}}
                \draw [densely dashed,blue] (marker-|0,0) -- (0,0);
                \draw plot [mark=*] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
             \else
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
             \fi
        }{
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}        
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
        \begin{scope}[options]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother

%% page settings%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry} % needed for page border stteings 
\parindent=0cm % for spece of first line of new text block
\sloppy % for writing with hypenless justification (tries to)
%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliograph style

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\parindent 0ex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead {}
\frenchspacing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \MakeUppercase {Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) in Ethiopia}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}%This affects the in spacing of my paragraphes
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{Section_1}
\input{Section_2}
\input{Section_3}
\input{Section_4}
\input{Section_5}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\includeonly{Chapter_1,Chapter_4}  % compile just chapters 1 and 4, space characters not permitted
\begin{document}
\include{Chapter_1}                % omit the '.tex' extension
\include{Chapter_2}
\include{Chapter_3}
\include{Chapter_4}
%both of these options did not help!

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{plain}
\Large{\textbf{Household Well-being in Ethiopia: Multidimensional Poverty, Time  Use to Work and Labor Productivity, and Nutrition Insecurity}}\\
\Large{\textbf{Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) in Ethiopia}}\\

\vfill
\line(1,0){400}\\ [1mm]%automatically putting vetical space btween the two elments to fill the page
\huge{\textbf{This is a sample title}}\\[3mm]
%\lipsum[1]
%{\setstretch{1.0}\color{blue}
%\lipsum[2]
%}
%\lipsum[3]
%\Large{\textbf{-This is a sample subtitle-}}\\[1mm]
\line(1,0){400}\\
\vfill    %Now it is centered at the page
By WELDESLASSIE HAILAI\\
Candidate\#:{214585063}\\
Supervisor Dr. Claire Vermaak\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\date {\today}
%\maketitle
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty} %This helps you to remove the page # in the table of contents part
\clearpage
%\chapter{Background and Justification}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[OC]{\leftmark}
%\fancyhead[EC]{\rightmark}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt} % needed to add a line at the bottom
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{1} %Now the f

\section{Background and Justifications}
...............
```

That is \include{Chapter} , \input{---}, \subfile{filename}, \documentclass{standalone} did not help or I failed to properly use these options... please HELP ASAP! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, but please don't post all  your actual code here, If you want to understand how to do things, make a sample document that shows the problem you're having. Most of the code you've posted has nothing to do with the problem at hand, so remove it.  It's also not clear what you want to do: include chapters into a larger document or include documents with different preambles into a larger document.

Comment: you have posted a lot of code but the question is completely unclear, and the code does not help us to understand it as we can not run it as it includes files we do not have. Please state clearly what output you get and what output you want. Also you appear to have the titlepage after chapter 4??

Comment: you should really clean up your preamble for example you load array twice, blkarray twice, tabuarx 4!! times, you load demo packages like lipsum, etc etc

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for your constructive comment. The question is simply how do I combine three independent threads of a research topic into one Thesis (book form)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm very appreciative for your constructive and problem-solving thoughts Sir. Yes. I strongly agree on that the preamble is very bad as I am the first time user of LaTex and was rushing to compile my first research work. I had to collect all stuff (including unimportant ones). I am editing it now, I am very appreciative and all comments and assistance will be welcome and well captured. The whole issue I had to learn by try and error, I am sorry for the clumsy presentations.

Comment: See (perhaps) [When should I use \input vs \include](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn Hello Sir, I did try that option, yet I did not win. Could please help me where exactly can enter /insert the \input and \include package in the preamble? Thank you for you sincerely and kind assistance.

Comment: your question is still not at all clear.. "three independent threads" is a description of the "subject matter", latex does not care about the subject matter at all, so you can have three chapters or three paragraphs or three sections about whatever subjects you like, it is just a single document to tex.  You have not said what problem you are having, if you get an error message show the error that you get, otherwise it is really impossible to help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for the misunderstanding. In simple words, I am trying to combine independent research topics into one Thesis. The code that I shared above is only for one topic; yet, I would like to combine three stand alone topics/research works into one big document. Any help?

Comment: there really is no need to try to combine the documents at that level (especially if the preambles are as complicated and weird as this) just start a new document, copy the _body_ of each of your documents in as chapters of the document and just add packages _if you need them_ (and only add them once)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[14.49998pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
```

there is no `14.49998pt` option, this must give a warning

```
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

I would use the standard `utf8` option unless you have a definite need for some of the `utf8x` features.

```
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %to plot figure
\usepackage{array, blkarray, tabularx, longtable, 
            multirow,threeparttable, makecell, booktabs, caption} 
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{tikz}


%\usepackage{booktabs}         %to use \toprule and \bottomrule without error message
```

The above line does nothing, the package is loaded above

```
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %to plot figure
```

The above line does nothing, the packages are loaded above

```
\usepackage{threeparttable}
```

The above line does nothing, the package is loaded above

```
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,caption}
```

The above line just loads caption, the other packages are  loaded above

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
```

The above line just loads  siunitx, the other packages are  loaded above

```
\sisetup{table-format=1.3} % default numerical column spec
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
```

The above line does nothing the packages are  loaded above

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

OK but you defined Y to be the same as C

```
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % default is 6pt
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage{subfigure}        % to add subfigures
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\textbf{#1}}%  to make heads of table in BOLD, it is used with booktabs package and \head
\usepackage{url} \makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}\makeatother
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url} \makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds} 
 \makeatother
```

The \usepackage line does nothing, package  loaded above , then you add UrlOrds a second time to UrlBreaks, which won't error but slows down all url processing

```
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
```

This will generate an error as you have already loaded caption without this option

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
```

This will do nothing as you can not pass oprions to a package after it is loaded

```
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
```

The above line does nothing, packages  loaded above

```
\usepackage{booktabs,csvsimple}
```

The above just loads cvssimple, booktabs package  loaded above

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm} % needed for command eqref or Math packages
\usepackage{amssymb} % needed for math fonts
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true
   ,breaklinks
   %, ngerman
    ] {hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the docuent, the option colorlink=true gets rid of the awful boxes, breaklinks breaks lonk links (list of figures), and the ngerman sets everthing for german s default hyperlink languages.
%\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
\definecolor {c1}{rgb}{0,0, 1} % blue
\definecolor {c2}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % light blue
\definecolor {c3}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % red blue
\hypersetup{
   linkcolor={c1}, % internal links
    citecolor={c2}, % citations 
    urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
}

%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for abbrvant bibliography style
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % needed for displaying bibliography and other in the table of contents
\usepackage{graphicx} % needed for\includegraphics
%\imp{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable} % needed for long tables over pages
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
\usepackage{bigstrut} % needed for the  command \bigstrut
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{blkarray}
%\usepackage{todonotes} % needed for todos
\usepackage{makeidx}  % needed for creating an index
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext} % needed for creating dummy text passage
```

You shouldn't have this in a real document

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

or this

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % needed for displayng bibliography and other in the able of contents
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
%\usepackage{figures}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

This is commented out but is the one package that you ought to be using

```
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}
```

The above just loads rotating, booktabs package  loaded above

```
\usepackage{lscape}
```

This has already been included by pdflascape

```
\usepackage{array}
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

The above line does nothing, package  loaded above

```
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,
                    labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[table]{font={footnotesize,sc},
                      labelsep=newline,
                      justification=centering}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*, fill=white}}
                \draw [densely dashed,blue] (marker-|0,0) -- (0,0);
                \draw plot [mark=*] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
             \else
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
             \fi
        }{
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}        
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
        \begin{scope}[options]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother

%% page settings%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry} % needed for page border stteings 
\parindent=0cm % for spece of first line of new text block
\sloppy % for writing with hypenless justification (tries to)
%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliograph style

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\parindent 0ex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead {}
\frenchspacing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \MakeUppercase {Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) in Ethiopia}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}%This affects the in spacing of my paragraphes
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

end of pramble...

```
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{Section_1}
\input{Section_2}
\input{Section_3}
\input{Section_4}
\input{Section_5}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\includeonly{Chapter_1,Chapter_4}  % compile just chapters 1 and 4, space characters not permitted
```

\includeonly should be in the document preamble, not here

```
\begin{document}
```

The above line will give an error you can not have two `\begin{document}`

```
\include{Chapter_1}                % omit the '.tex' extension
\include{Chapter_2}
\include{Chapter_3}
\include{Chapter_4}
%both of these options did not help!

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{plain}
\Large{\textbf{Household Well-being in Ethiopia: Multidimensional Poverty,
```

size commands do not take an argument, the syntax is `{\large abc}` not `\large{abc}`

Time  Use to Work and Labor Productivity, and Nutrition Insecurity}}\
    \Large{\textbf{Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) in Ethiopia}}\

`{\Large` not `\Large{`

```
\vfill
\line(1,0){400}\\ [1mm]%automatically putting vetical space btween the two elments to fill the page
\huge{\textbf{This is a sample title}}\\[3mm]
```

`{\huge` not `huge{`

```
%\lipsum[1]
%{\setstretch{1.0}\color{blue}
%\lipsum[2]
%}
%\lipsum[3]
%\Large{\textbf{-This is a sample subtitle-}}\\[1mm]
\line(1,0){400}\\
\vfill    %Now it is centered at the page
By WELDESLASSIE HAILAI\\
Candidate\#:{214585063}\\
Supervisor Dr. Claire Vermaak\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\date {\today}
%\maketitle
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty} %This helps you to remove the page # in the table of contents part
\clearpage
%\chapter{Background and Justification}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[OC]{\leftmark}
%\fancyhead[EC]{\rightmark}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt} % needed to add a line at the bottom
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{1} %Now the f

\section{Background and Justifications}
...............
```

---

---

---

To make a document consisting of three other documents just arrange things so each of the small documents looks like

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{..}
\begin{document}
\input{document_1_body}
\end{document}
```

where `document_1_body.tex`,  `document_2_body.tex`,  `document_3_body.tex` are the texts of the documents without the preamble, then your combined document is simply

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{....}
\begin{document}
\chapter{doc one}
\input{document_1_body}
\chapter{doc two}
\input{document_2_body}
\chapter{doc three}
\input{document_3_body}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @AlanMunn I have been terminated my PhD research due to personal & family reasons. I'm planning  kick off my research. Yet, I lost my laptop & all the application software  including Latex. How could I retrieve my previous work form here and restart my research?                                                                                                Thank you.

Comment: @HailaiWeldeslassie you never posted your chapters here so they can not be retrieved from here, sorry. (your ping to Alan would not work under my answer, pings only work if the system auto-completes thename when you type `@` and the first letter.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply @DavidCarlisle. So I must start from zero?

Comment: @HailaiWeldeslassie you can see all the text that you posted here, and can of course copy it back, but it is just your top level file.  not any of the files that are \input, I don't know where you think they would be on this site? Sorry we can not help more.

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle, thank you. I will copy the top-level file and try to combine it with the old word file outputs. This was converted from the PDF file output. I wonder if that works out.   I will come back when I need technical assistance.